Derive a sharp bound of this integral using the transformation formula and/or Taylor's theorem
Let

$d\in\mathbb N$;
$\sigma\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ and $\Sigma:=\sigma\sigma^\ast$;
$b:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ be Borel measurable;
$\Delta t>0$;
$\kappa(x,\;\cdot\;)$ denote the normal distribution with mean $x+\Delta tb(x)$ and covariance $\Sigma$ for $x\in\mathbb R^d$.

Note that $\kappa$ is a Markov kernel and hence can be considered as a bounded linear operator on $L^2(\lambda^{\otimes d})$, where $\lambda^{\otimes d}$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$. The adjoint of this operator should be given by $$(\kappa^\ast g)(y)=\frac1{\sqrt{(2\pi)^d\det\Sigma}}\int\lambda^{\otimes d}({\rm d}x)e^{-\frac12\left\langle\Sigma^{-1}\left(y-\left(x+\Delta tb(x)\right)\right),\;y-\left(x+\Delta tb(x)\right)\right\rangle}g(x)\tag1$$ for all $y\in\mathbb R^d$ and $g\in L^2(\lambda^{\otimes d})$.
Now, for $g\in C^2(\mathbb R^d)$, I would actually need to compute $(\kappa^\ast g)(y)$ (for a finite set of $y$) in a computer program. However, my assumption is that evaluation of $g$ is expensive. Moreover, for the choice of $b,g$ I'm interested in, which is $b=\frac12\Sigma\nabla\ln g$, it will hold $(\kappa^\ast g)(y)\xrightarrow{\Delta t\to0+}0$. However, practically, $\Delta t$ will not be crazily small, but around $.01$.
So, what I'm looking for is a sharp bound of $|(\kappa^\ast g)(y)|$ of the form $$|(\kappa^\ast g)(y)|\le c(y,\Delta t)\tag2$$ with $c(y,\Delta t)\xrightarrow{\Delta t\to0+}0$ when $b=\frac12\Sigma\nabla\ln g$.
I already played around with the transformation formula $$\int f\;{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}=\int(f\circ\phi)|\det{\rm D}\phi|\;{\rm d}\lambda^{\otimes d}\tag3$$ and Taylor's theorem in the form $$g(x)=g(y)+\langle\nabla g(y),x-y\rangle+\frac12\left\langle{\rm D}^2g(y)(x-y),x-y\right\rangle+h_y(x)\|x-y\|^2\tag4$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^d$ for some continuous $h_y:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ for all $y\in\mathbb R^d$.
Any idea on how this could be performed in a smart way is highly appreciated.
